# Track Form fills using Google Analytics/ Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to track my form fills. I want to know which pages did the user went to before filling up the form. How can I track this in Google Analytics or Google Tag manager? Looking for a step by step solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Google Analytics
2. (Property your tracking)
3. Click "Behavior" on the side panel
4. Click "Behavior Flow"

This gives you a flowchart of what steps visitors took to get to specific pages. Find your sign-up/thank-you page and work backwards.